# using react-native-tab-view on expo on press tab not working but on local device its working fine

Tags: react-native, expo, components, slider, npm-package

I am using npm I react-native-tab-view two create slider

installed Expo app first the tab view onPressTap is not working I have separately implement the on press tab there

after this

installed app on local device through android studio its working problem without mentioning onPressTap on clicked both the tap are working and slider is moving to respective pages

Why this happened is due to expo not supporting this library

react-native-tab-view
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view

I try to installed app from expo not working then install locally through android studio its working properly.